# Lorentz transformation matrix identity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, matrix-elements

I know that the following statement is equilvelent to saying a matrix times its inverse is the identity matrix

$$ \Lambda^\mu_{\rho '}\Lambda^{\rho'}_{\nu}=\delta^\mu_\nu$$

but i would like to show it in subscript notation using the relations:

\begin{equation}
x^{\mu '} = \Lambda^{\mu'}_{\nu}x^\nu
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
x^{\mu} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\nu'}x^{\nu'}
\end{equation}

So far what ive done is write
$$x^{\nu'}=\Lambda^{\nu'}_{\mu}x^\mu$$

sub that into the second equation and times both sides by the inverse of $x^{\mu}$ to get

$$x^{\mu}(x^{\mu})^{-1} = \Lambda^{\mu}_{\rho'}\Lambda^{\rho'}_{\mu}x^{\mu}(x^{\mu})^{-1}$$

then said that the on the RHS we have the identity and on the LHS we have the Kroneker delta but that feels very wrong I haven't really used subscript notation much so im sorry for all the mistakes but can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Your indices do not match correctly in your fourth equation.

Comment: @Charlie Thanks fixed that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it makes sense here to talk about the inverse of the contravariant vector. Inverses are defined in terms of some operation. So the additive inverse of an integer is its negative. And we can define the inverse of a matrix under matrix multiplication. For vectors we usually don't define any such inverse under inner or outer products. You can see that the way you're doing it you get a contradiction, since $\Lambda_\mu^\nu \Lambda_\nu^\mu = \delta_\mu^\mu = 4$, which doesn't match with your 4th equation.

One way to see your identity is this:

$$
x^{\nu'} = \Lambda_\mu^{\nu'} x^\mu \\
x^{\mu} = \Lambda_{\nu'}^\mu x^{\nu'} \\
x^{\nu'} = \Lambda_\mu^{\nu'} x^\mu = \Lambda_\mu^{\nu'} \Lambda_{\rho'}^\mu x^{\rho'} = \delta_{\rho'}^{\nu'} x^{\rho'} \\
\boxed{\Lambda_\mu^{\nu'} \Lambda_{\rho'}^\mu = \delta_{\rho'}^{\nu'}}
$$

Hope that helps!